# the fundamental period

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi : I'm reading the signals and systems schaum's book and I ran into a question based on one of the exercises. This is the most relevant tag I could find so I apologize if there is a better one.

How does one compute the fundamental period of

A) $cos 4(t) +  sin(6t)$

B) $sin^2(t)$

in both cases, it's $\pi$ but I'm not clear on how this answer was obtained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental period is the smallest $T$ such that the function is $T$-periodic, i.e. $f(x) = f(x+T)$. For $\sin x$ the fundamental period is $2\pi$, and therefore the fundamental period of $\sin nx$ is $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ (because if you add $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ to $x$, $nx$ increases by $2\pi$).

Now take two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ with fundamental periods $T_f$ and $T_g$. For every $n$, you thus know that $f(x+nT_f) = f(x)$ and $g(x+nT_g) = g(x)$. What, then, is the fundamental period of $h(x) = f(x) + g(x)$? We're going to need a $T$ such that there are $n_f$ and a $n_g$ with $$
  T = n_fT_f = n_gT_g
$$
because then $$
  h(x + nT) = f(x + nT) + g(x + nT) = f(x + nn_fT_f) + g(x + nn_gT_g) = f(x) + g(x) = h(x) \text{.}
$$
Since we're looking for the *fundamental* period, we're going to want the smallest $n_f,n_g$ for which this works. By rewriting the condition, you obtain $$
  \frac{n_f}{n_g} = \frac{T_g}{T_f} \text{,}
$$
i.e. we need to find the *quotient* of $T_g$ and $T_f$. Note, however, that this only really provides you with a *candidate* for the fundamental period. If, for example, you add $f(x)$ and $-f(x)$, the result is $0$, and which doesn't have a well-defined fundamental period.

For $\underbrace{\cos(4t)}_{=f(t)} + \underbrace{\cos(6t)}_{=g(t)}$ you thus get $$
  \frac{n_f}{n_g} = \frac{\frac{2\pi}{6}}{\frac{2\pi}{4}} = \frac{2}{3}
$$
and from that $$
  T = 2\frac{2\pi}{4} = 3\frac{2\pi}{6} = 2\pi
$$

For products, you can do the same as for sums - the derivation above doesn't really depend on $h(x)$ being a sum, it works for *any* combination of $f$ and $g$, so long as $x$ isn't *explicitly* used, only indirectly via $f$ and $g$. But $\sin^2x$ turns out to be another example where the method above only provides you with *some* period, not always the fundamental one. If you read $\sin^2 x$ as $(\sin x)(\sin x)$, that method will yield $T = 2\pi$, because that is the period of $\sin x$, and so $n_f = n_g = 1$. But squaring a sine wave *doubles* its frequences, and so *halves* the period length, so the fundamental period of $\sin^2x$ is actually $$
  T = \pi
$$

---

This, BTW, also tells you that the sum $f(x) + g(x)$ is *not* periodic if the quotient of the periods of $f$ and $g$ isn't rational. Can you see why?

Comment: wow. that's an amazingly thorough and clear answer. I am closing the answer out with a check.

Comment: I think it's because $\frac{n_{f}}{n_{g}}$ won't be integers divided by each other so it won't be clear what to multiply the respective fundamental periods by to get the overall resulting fundamental period. Is that correct ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @markleeds Exactly - you won't find *any* $n_f,n_g$ then with $n_f T_f = n_g T_g$.